# Is it possible to use $lang variable in fatal_error output on front end?

Tags: add-on-development, module, language, custom-system-messages

In my custom module I want to display a series of error messages for X, Y & Z. I have a single tag in the mod.[module_name].php file and I want to throw out an error if no id has been provided.

```
if ( !ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('contact_id') ) {
    ee()->output->fatal_error(lang('missing_contact_id'));
}
```

Now when I add the tag without the id the message appears but with the text 'missing_contact_id' rather than what is defined in my $lang language file.

Is there a way to output this on the front end?

It's worth noting that all my language strings are displaying correctly from the various functions in the mcp.[module_name].php file and the views that I have set up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an answer over at ExpressionEngine [link](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html#9460)

In case the link dies here is what is posted:

> "If you want to display language messages in from end templates (for
>   instance, in error messages) you must explicitly load the language
>   file. Without loading it, the CP will render the language items just
>   fine, but the front-end will not. So, in the hook function or
>   constructor, load your language file like so:"

```
// if your lang file is named example_lang.php
public function __construct($settings = '') {
    $this->EE =& get_instance();
    $this->settings = $settings;
    $this->EE->lang->loadfile('example');
}
```

> or if you have a function for instance:

```
function cartthrob_pre_process() {
    $this->EE->lang->loadfile('example');
    $this->EE->output->show_user_error('general', lang('minimum_not_met') );
}
```

Just a quick note, mine was called lang.module_name.php so I just used

`ee()->lang->loadfile('module_name')`